# Question concerning short-cirquit operators and post-fix incrementation in Java 8 (OCA)

Tags: java, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I'm studying for my OCA certification and found this piece of code and was wondering why the result of the code below is "1, 2" and not "1, 3".

The '&' operator used here is not short cirquit, and the postfix increment is applied to the first int, so why not to the second?

```java
  int i = 0;
  int j = 1;
  if( (i++ == 0) & (j++ == 2) ){
     i = 12;
  }
  System.out.println(i+" "+j);
```

*edit Taking breaks is important while studying. I understood the concepts involved but fatigue let me make a logical error which made me assume j started out as 2*

Comment: `j++ = j + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2`. Why should `j` be 3?

Comment: Because i've been studying too long and it appears my brain had already tapped out.. But thanks for the help hha..

Comment: This would do exactly the same if you used `&&` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would `j` be `3` when it is incremented only once in the `if` block `j++ == 2`. Initially `j` is initialized to `1` then the `++` operator was applied which incremented it to `2`.

`++` operator is essentially doing `j = j + 1`, and since you used the logical AND operator `&` both the first condition and second condition was evaluated.

Note: If the first condition was evaluated to false still the second condition would have been evaluated as `&` is the logical AND operator and not the conditional `&&` operator which is short circuiting.

Logical operators as described in the [javase specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22).

Comment: I'll accept your answer since you went through the trouble of writing it all out. Thanks! The concepts used here were quite clear to me, but I might've been on it for a bit too long today.

Comment: @matthewkeissard you can check you the behavior of bitwise logical operators in the java spec I posted in my answer.

Comment: It's not the bitwise and operator. It's the logical and operator.

Comment: @AndyTurner my bad, **bitwise** when the operands are **numeric** and **logical** when operands are **boolean**, am I right?

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick you are approximately correct. The part of the language spec you link in your answer describes it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marvin noted in the comments, j++ = j + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2.

It's Important to take regular breaks when studying for your OCA certification :)